# Calculating differences between two dates results in a wrong calculation

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure something out on my own,

today's date of 11/25/2014 minus 11/26/2014 should result in a calculation of -1

today's date of 11/25/2014 minus 11/25/2014 should result in a calculation of 0

today's date of 11/25/2014 minus 11/24/2014 should result in a calculation of 1

The function below seems wrong, I need a fresh set of eyes.

```
var today = new Date()

var date1 = new Date("11/26/2014");

var diffDays = Math.ceil((today.getTime() - date1.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));

alert(diffDays)
```

The function as it is displays a result 0 which is wrong.

Comment: Math.ceil of a -0.18377817129629628 will return zero. That would be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need math.round or math.abs:

```
var today = new Date()

var date1 = new Date("11/26/2014");

var diffDays = Math.round((today.getTime() - date1.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));

alert(diffDays)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the difference, irrespective of the order, you will need to `Math.abs` to ensure you don't have a negative number.

```
var diffDays = Math.ceil(Math.abs(today.getTime() - date1.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Answer (score 0):

The date difference will result in -0.42831302083333334, Math.ceil() will round it up towards the closest *positive* integer, which will result in 0.